# Reserve 2D std::vector of Widgets

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++17, c++14

For some legacy code reasons, I have to live with below code

```
// Header.h

class Widget
{
   // bunch of primitive types 
   // no fancy C++11 ish member functions

};

class BigWidget
{
   std::vector<std::vector<Widget>> w2dlist;
};

// Source.cpp

void someFunction()
{
   // some runtime calculations of numRows and numCols

    w2dlist.reserve(numRows);

    for (auto& r : w2dlilst)
    {
        r.reserve(numCols);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) 
    {
        w2dlist.emplace_back();   // emplace some default constructed objects
        
        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) 
        {
===>>>            w2dlist[i].emplace_back(); // do the same 
        }
    }
}
```

I can not change the Widget/BigWidget class with rule of 4/5 members.
But the profiler is pointing the line in the inner loop as one of the hotspots.

How can I improve this ?

I have tried below tricks

1. default construct Widget as `Widget{}` while emplace'in , the static checker (and eventually runtime) point to stack overflow and crashes the app
2. default construct/reserve 2D vector in BigWidget constructor, profiler then shifts the hotspot to this operation
3. Meyer's singleton while emplacin' the Widgets :D , profiler is merciless

Profiler/Compiler : Visual Studio 2019 (C++17)

OS : Windows

Comment: The only possible optimization in the limited amount of shown, incomplete, code would be to use `reserve()`, accordingly. That will result in some minor performance improvement, but it's unlikely to be dramatic.

Comment: "I can not change the Widget/BigWidget class with rule of 4/5 members. " this is unclear. They both do follow the rule of 0 which seems to be just fine.

Comment: `w2dlist = std::vector<std::vector<Widget>>(numRows, std::vector<Widget>(numCols));`?

Comment: After `w2dlist.reserve(numRows);`, `w2dlist` is still empty. Thus, `for (auto& r : w2dlist)` does zero iterations and allocates no memory.

Comment: Fwiw, If you do something often in your code then the profiler will identify it as hotspot. That does not necessarily mean that it is also the place where you can gain lots of performance. Thats up to you to check. I wouldnt be too surprised if you do add a reserve, and then still the profiler shows this part as hotspot (even though you did all you can already)

Comment: Also, you *are* profiling an optimized build, right?